# Passed function has a variable not working

Tags: javascript

I have the below javascript however am now getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: responseHandler is not a function`

```
var Message = {
    initialMessageList: function(profile_id) {
            $('.messages-list profile'+ profile_id).html = '<div class="message-loader profile"+ profile_id><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
            Message.fetchMessageList(profile_id, Message.initialMessageListHandler('', profile_id));
        }

        initialMessageListHandler: function(data, profile_id) {
            $('.messages-list .message-loader profile'+ profile_id).remove();
            $('.messages-list profile'+ profile_id).html(Message.getMessageListHtml(data));
            Message.bindMessageList();
            $('.open-message profile'+ profile_id).first().click();
        },

        fetchMessageList: function(query, responseHandler) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app/messages/fetch/' + query,
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'get'
            })
                .done(function(response) {
                    responseHandler(response); <--- this is the line it errors on
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
                        window.location = '/';
                    } else {
                        responseHandler([]);
                    }
                });
        },
```

This is after changing from:

```
initialMessageList: function(profile_id) {
        $('.messages-list profile'+ profile_id).html = '<div class="message-loader profile"+ profile_id><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
        Message.fetchMessageList(profile_id, Message.initialMessageListHandler);
    },

    initialMessageListHandler: function(data) {
        $('.messages-list .message-loader ').remove();
        $('.messages-list ').html(Message.getMessageListHtml(data));
        Message.bindMessageList();
        $('.open-message ').first().click();
    },

    fetchMessageList: function(query, responseHandler) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/messages/fetch/' + query,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'get'
        })
            .done(function(response) {
                responseHandler(response);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
                    window.location = '/';
                } else {
                    responseHandler([]);
                }
            });
    },
```

Comment: Whatever you pass into that function as a handler isn't a function. Use a debugger breakpoint to look at what `responseHandler` is.

Comment: Where do you define `responseHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're not passing in the function, but the result of the called function, which is what happens when you add the parentheses.

```
fetchMessageList(profile_id, Message.initialMessageListHandler('', profile_id));

fetchMessageList: function(query, responseHandler) {
    responseHandler(); // error, "undefined"
}
```

Note how you're calling `initialMessageListHandler`, and it has no return value, so it returns undefined, so what you're really doing is

```
fetchMessageList(profile_id, undefined);

fetchMessageList: function(query, responseHandler) {
    responseHandler(); // error, "undefined"
}
```

And what you should be doing is

```
fetchMessageList(profile_id, function() {
    Message.initialMessageListHandler('', profile_id)
});
```

using an anonymous function as a wrapper, when you have to pass arguments like that

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way: you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) needed parameters to your function like

```
Message.fetchMessageList(profile_id, Message.initialMessageListHandler.bind(null,'', profile_id));
```